# change bitmap resolution in Android app

Tags: android, bitmap, resolution

I'm writing an application that uses the phone's camera to take a picture, and then use it in my app. The thing is, the app runs out of memory, and it is probably because of the bitmap's high resolution. Is there a way to keep the bitmap at the same size, but lower the resolution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done using Options.inSampleSize, when creating the bitmap

Comment: Isn't that for the size? What if you want to just manipulate the resolution without changing the size?

Answer (score 5):

You can Set Its Width and Height

```
Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(imagefile, 150, 150);
```

Function to Call

```
Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){

 BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
    {
     if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
     {
      bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
     } else {
      bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
     }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
 return bitmap;
}
```

}

This are two more links which might Help You. [Link 1](http://androidbyhp.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-how-to-reduce-size-of-bitmaps.html)  & [Link 2](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/)

Comment: this works when I'm using the decodeResource option to get my bitmap. But, when workingfrom the get image intent, I get a Uri and do this:
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri); 

Is there a way to resize after I have the bitmap in this way?