# reduce DPI resolution of bitmap in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change bitmap resolution in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958362/change-bitmap-resolution-in-android-app)

how to reduce DPI (Horizontal Resolution and vertical resolution ) of image or bitmap in android ?

Answer (score 1):

By "reduce DPI" do you mean scaling image? If so then try this code

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, false);
```

Comment: i have reduce Resolution  of image(Horizontal Resolution and vertical resolution)